# Error handling (400) in app engine with Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, error-handling

I want to handle in my app engine application the error 400. 
I could handle the 404 error using the following code:

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
public void unmappedRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getRequestURI();
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    throw new UnknownResourceException("There is no resource for path "
    + uri);
}
```

and then i manage the 404 error.

However, for the 400 error (bad request), I tried something like this:

in web.xml

```
  <error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/error/400</location>
  </error-page>
```

and then in my controller

```
@RequestMapping("/error/400")
public void badRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    request.getRequestURI();
    String uri = request.getRequestURI();
    throw new UnknownResourceException("bad request for path " + uri);
}
```

But it doesn't work, so I'm getting the default error screen from app engine when I make a bad request.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the easiest and quickest solution I got finally was doing something like this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
    public String handleMyException(Exception exception,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    return "/error/myerror";
    }
}
```

The key here is to handle the org.springframework.web.bind.**MissingServletRequestParameterException**;

Other alternative, It also can be done through the web.xml, like the following:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException</exception-type>
    <location>/WEB-INF/error/myerror.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 2):

The entry

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/error/400</location>
</error-page>
```

results in the servlet container making a `RequestDispatcher#forward` to the `location` element. This won't map to a `@Controller`, but to a servlet (url-mapped) or a jsp, or other.

Use an `@ExceptionHandler`. For examples (with specific Exceptions), see [here](http://doanduyhai.wordpress.com/2012/05/06/spring-mvc-part-v-exception-handling/).