# Tomcat 7 default bad request page conflict @ControllerAdvice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am currently developing a webservice which will always return json as a response to any request(all good request are working already). I would like to return a json when the http status of the request is a bad request(status 400 to be exact). I used the `@ControllerAdvice` of spring mvc to do the job:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestErrorHandler {

@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
@ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, reason="Something went wrong. Please check your JSON REQUEST!")
public @ResponseBody ErrorClass processValidationError() {

    // some stuff in setting the error response

    return new ErrorClass();
}
```

But what happen is that it returns the default Tomcat 7 error message for bad request and not the json I set. `processValidationError()` will return an `ErrorClass` instance which will automatically be in json format using `jackson plugin`. Did I missed something?

Comment: Can you try something like : [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18549456/error-handling-400-in-app-engine-with-spring-3)

Comment: There's a lot more than `MethodArgumentNotValidException` that triggers a 400 response.

Comment: Yeap, you need to handle each one of them. Which one is being thrown right now? You can use a generic exception to discover.

Comment: just edited the code. I want it to handle all exception.